# Need to call a function (referenced by static pointer) from a static member

Tags: c++

everyone.
Recently I face the challenge. Cannot say that it was a critical problem, but just an interesting thing.
There is src code:

```
class Data {
typedef void (Object::*CallBack)(void);

public:
Data() : m_callBack(NULL) {}
void setCallBack(CallBack ptr)
{
    m_callBack = ptr;
}
void start()
{
    Aux::someAction();
}

private:
static CallBack m_callBack;

class Aux{
    public:
    static someAction()
    {
        if(m_callBack)
        {
            // How to call function for this reference ? - m_callBack
        }
    }
}; // End of 'Aux' class
}; // End of 'Data' class
```

So, I know that we can call functions from pointers like that: (this->*m_callBack)(). But static class members do not have an access to ‘this’ pointer. Of course, I can store a pointer of a parent with m_callBack pointer and call (parent->*m_callBack)(). In same cases it may be not so good.
So, my question: Is there any other methods to call m_callBack function from a static class member. Also, I’m interesting about – if m_callBack references to class member of static OR non static function.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the member variable m_callBack public if you want it to work. Then you could write

```
Data::setCallback(...);

...

Data::m_callBack();
```

or rather

```
if ( Data::m_callBack )
{
   Data::m_callBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a design problem. Either you want to have a non-static `Callback` (i.e., `m_callBack`) or you want to typedef your Callback as a static function (i.e. that does not need `this`).